# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence while training CNN using tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I know this question had been asked a lot, but I still can't fix it, I'm using my own dataset of images and I cropped some of them in photoshop "if it has to do anything with the problem " then every time I try to train the network, I got this error. this is my code:

```
def create_train_data():
training_data = []
for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
    path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)
    img_data = cv2.imread(path, 0)
    try:

        img_data = cv2.resize(img_data, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    except:
        exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
        f = tb.tb_frame
        lineno = tb.tb_lineno
        filename = img
        linecache.checkcache(filename)
        line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
        print('EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj))
    training_data.append([np.array(img_data), create_label(img)])

shuffle(training_data)
np.save('women_train_data.npy', training_data)
return training_data

def create_test_data():
  testing_data = []
  for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TEST_DIR)):
     path = os.path.join(TEST_DIR, img)
     img_num = img.split('.')[1]
     img_data = cv2.imread(path, 0)
    try:

        img_data = cv2.resize(img_data, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    except:
        exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
        f = tb.tb_frame
        lineno = tb.tb_lineno
        filename = img
        linecache.checkcache(filename)
        line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
        print('EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(filename, lineno, 
        line.strip(), exc_obj))
    testing_data.append([np.array(img_data), create_label(img)])
np.save('women_test_data.npy', testing_data)
return testing_data


 tf.reset_default_graph()

 if os.path.exists('women_train_data.npy'):
    train_data = np.load('women_train_data.npy')
 else:
    train_data = create_train_data()

if os.path.exists('women_test_data.npy'):
   test_data = np.load('women_test_data.npy')
else:
    test_data = create_test_data()

  train = train_data
  test = test_data

  print (train.shape)


X_train = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y_train = [i[1] for i in train]
X_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y_test = [i[1] for i in test]

conv_input = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')

conv1 = conv_2d(conv_input, 32, 5, activation='relu')
pool1 = max_pool_2d(conv1, 5)

conv2 = conv_2d(pool1, 64, 5, activation='relu')
pool2 = max_pool_2d(conv2, 5)

conv3 = conv_2d(pool2, 128, 5, activation='relu')
pool3 = max_pool_2d(conv3, 5)

conv4 = conv_2d(pool3, 64, 5, activation='relu')
pool4 = max_pool_2d(conv4, 5)

conv5 = conv_2d(pool4, 32, 5, activation='relu')
pool5 = max_pool_2d(conv5, 5)

fully_layer = fully_connected(pool5, 1024, activation='relu')
fully_layer = dropout(fully_layer, 0.8)

cnn_layers = fully_connected(fully_layer, 56, activation='softmax')
cnn_layers = regression(cnn_layers, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, 
loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(cnn_layers, tensorboard_dir='log', 
tensorboard_verbose=3)

if os.path.exists('women_model.tfl.meta'):
    model.load('./model.tfl')

else:
   model.fit({'input': X_train}, {'targets': y_train}, n_epoch=10,
          validation_set=({'input': X_test}, {'targets': y_test}),
          snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
        model.save('women_model.tfl')
```

I tried this code with cat vs dog dataset from Kaggel and it worked fine, I had also  this problem with different dataset but after using it with different project but same code and reusing it with this code suddenly it worked but I didn't complete the training so I'm not sure if I will have the same problem,
I know this could be from an array that contains different lengths for the lists inside, but all the data are coming from the images so I don't 
have full control over the input, so how I could fix that?

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found the solution on one of the youtube comments it turns out that I should add a hardcoded vector with zeros in case I labeled one of the images wrong ex:

```
if label == man_black_shirt
   np.array([0,0,0,1]
else:
   np.array([0,0,0,0])
```

sorry for my lack of exprince,and i feel the error was misleading or it has something to do with the array length problem that i don't know,i hope that help someomne in future